# Render images using blend4web

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend4web

I came across a problem with blender materials. I use both blender and blend4web materials. What happens is blend4web materials aren't rendered sometimes. Is it possible to use blend4web instead of "Blender render" to render images?

Comment: Blend4Web is not an external render engine in the strict sense of the word. You can't directly render images with it, nor are there blend4web specific materials. As far as I know they are simply Blender internal materials with a few extra setting on top.

Comment: You might try asking on the B4W forums: https://www.blend4web.com/ru/forums/